# Bash webapp duplicator

Tags: bash, wordpress, drupal

I've written the following Bash script used to duplicate a webapp/website you have (say, a Wordpress website) locally on your server environment, for testing purposes, indicating after 2 days if you have yet to delete it after you've finished your testing.

Here's the code:

```
cat <<-'DWA' > /opt/dwa.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    DWA() {
        tiesto='tiesto'
        read domain
        find /var/www/html ${domain} -exec cp ${domain} ${tiesto} {} \;
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${tiesto}'/g /var/www/html/tiesto/wp-config
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${tiesto}'/g /var/www/html/tiesto/wp-config
        mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
            create user '${tiesto}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
            create database ${tiesto};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${tiesto}.* TO ${tiesto}@localhost;
        MYSQL
        sleep 2d
        echo "If you haven't already, eliminate tiesto (dir & db)."
        tmux kill-session
    }
    DWA
DWA
chmod +x /opt/dwa.sh && cat >> /etc/bash.bashrc <<< "alias dwa='tmux new-session -d bash /opt/dwa.sh'"
```

After a `reboot` (due to the added alias), run it by the alias + an argument to indicate the app you're working on.

For example, if you named the app/site as example.com (I assume you named the site's dir, the DB user, and the DB instance **the same**), execute this in Bash:

```
dwa example.com
```

The webapp/site should be duplicated.

I would appreciate your review.

Comment: Contribute to the github project [here](https://github.com/benqzq/dwa), if you wish.